# In GraphDB, importing seeAlso and isDefinedBy resources as RDF content

Tags: rdf, rdfs, graphdb

I import a RDF document in GraphDB, with rdfs:seeAlso and rdfs:isDefinedBy resources,
and these resources URLs point to valid RDF content.

This document is correctly loaded in GraphDB and I can see the seeAlso and isDefinedBy links.

But what I expect is to be able to import the content of these URLs (Right-click, command or whatever),
just as importing these URLs independently.

Instead, GraphDB just allows to click and display their content as text.

Does it mean that my assumption that GraphDB considers seeAlso and isDefinedBy links as distant RDF resources, is wrong ?

And is there any mean to browse / import RDF resources in an RDF document ?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a Linked Data dereferencing feature in GraphDB but I might be wrong. As a workaround, you could do it via a small command line script or something which downloads the RDF data and then loads the data into the triple store. I mean, it's simply doing an HTTP request with the appropriate content format request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rdfs:seeAlso indicates that a resource might provide additional information about the subject resource. Currently there's no way to load the relations as distant resources in GraphDB as you described, but it's a good idea for future improvement. However you can use federation as an alternative to join multiple resource sources.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of RDF (LD) crawling frameworks that you can use to collect resources for loading. Many of them follow all kinds of links, but I hope at least one can be configured to follow the links you are interested in.